# How to generate java code from an Eclipse GEF Model

Tags: eclipse-gef, eclipse-emf

I have GEF WYSIWYG model but now I want to generate java code as GWT does. How to achieve this. Is it by EMF or some other tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Java Emitter Templates to see if this would fulfil your needs:

http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/m2t/?project=jet#jet

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-JET/jet_tutorial1.html